# Power to triac dimmer and arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I am building 2 channel triac dimmer to control led strip lights in my pantry.  Have 4 channel Krida module (just use two, I guess) and Uno.  Have had some success with the triacDimmer library examples, but now realize I'm not sure of my basic approach.

I want to have two light circuits ramp up to a preset light level, then stay on until the power cuts out.  My question is this:  is it possible to power the Arduino Uno and the AC going into the triac module from the same switch?    Will the microcontroller just "start over" every time the power comes on to it - and will the triac be in "off" status without power to its gate?

This is a matter of design, and I'm way out of my depths.  I want to power this project, and write the sketch, so that the two circuits fade on to a  pre-set level when the power comes on.  Is it ok to plan to turn off the lights by just 'pulling the plug?'

Please let me know if this is still not an appropriate question for this forum.  I appreciate any help or feedback.  Thanks

Comment: please remove all the non-arduino parts of your post ... ask a specific answerable question about the arduino ... it would help a lot if you provided a diagram of your proposed wiring configuration

Answer (score 1):

You ask: "is it possible to power the Arduino Uno and the AC going into the triac module from the same switch? Will the microcontroller just "start over" every time the power comes on to it - and will the triac be in "off" status without power to its gate?"
Yes you can put a switch in the line that powers the primary side that feeds both the lights and the UNO power supply. The 4 channel Krida module I have does not turn on the lights until I power the optocoupler. I also have one that has a processor on board and it behaves the same way. When you write your code get a 24V transformer and two 24V lamps to debug your project, that way you will not fry yourself. This is how I normally prototype 120 and 240 Volt circuits. I then test it with the mains when it is all assembled and the test equipment disconnected. Remember some best equipment especially bench type has a connection to the earth ground.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  I have hit wall with trying to use/adapt either of two sketches.  Is there a good place in this forum to post software questions? I remember when dimmers we're really simple

Comment: The Krida module comes in many varieties. Go to the website where you purchased it they will probably have examples of the code for the Arduino. This link was my first try: https://www.tindie.com/products/bugrovs2012/ardutex-trailing-edge-i2c-ac-led-light-dimmer/